# dotnet core encryption and sql server decryption

Tags: .net, encryption, hmac

I have a requirement to store user specific data in sql tables which will later process using stored proceedures. Is it possible to decrypt the data in stored procedure which are encrypted in .net application using Hmac sha algorithm?

Comment: As an alternative, if you need to process the data with stored procedures then perhaps the information at [SQL Server Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/sql-server-encryption?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Your requirement means that leaked database should not leak confidential data. Lets suppose that it is possible to decrypt data in stored procedure. It would mean that the key to decrypt data is located in database itself which potentially can be accessed by hacker (either through dump or direct access). As you can see you are placing confidential data into safe, place the key near the door of the safe and walk away. Is it really what you trying to achieve?